# Length required when accessing the pages from mobile Samsung GT-I5700

Tags: android, mobile

when I try to access to my site, from samsung mobile , the browser is displaying "`Length required.`"
It is working on HTC legend mobile.

What could be the cause?

To make a site to be compatible with most mobiles , any good references idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout this website http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E411.html